# Perform action before resetTopViewAnimated on tap gesture

Tags: ecslidingviewcontroller

I am trying to perform an action (removing a subview) every time the side menus are closed. But I want this action to be performed before resetTopViewAnimated starts.

I only have the TapGesture (no slide) configured on my ECSlidingViewController.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing and reading, I was able to understand the Custom Gestures when using ECSlidingViewController.

It's quite simple actually!

Create your custom gesture:

```
- (UITapGestureRecognizer *)localTapGesture {
    if (_localTapGesture) return _localTapGesture;

    _localTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(customResetTopView)];

    return _localTapGesture;
}
```

When instantiating your slidingViewController, set the topViewAnchoredGesture to use a Custom Gesture:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewAnchoredGesture = ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGestureCustom;
```

Then just add the Gesture Recognizer you created as one of the customAnchoredGestures:

```
self.slidingViewController.customAnchoredGestures = @[self.localTapGesture];
```